# How to make a Button Visible/Gone on scroll listener of gridView in Android

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-gridview

I have a Custom gridView and a Button in Frame Layout. Code is following

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Rel_Spinner"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLoadMore"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Load More" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It loads images and Text from adapter. as shown in figure

[image]

Now I want is that the Button should appear when the final position of the GridView Scroll is reached other wise it should again disappear. as shown in figure.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by using [setOnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) for GridView as:

```
gridview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

   @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
              int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

      }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      switch(scrollState) {
        case 2: // SCROLL_STATE_FLING 
        //hide button here
        break;

        case 1: // SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL 
        //hide button here
        break;

        case 0: // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE 
        //show button here
        break;

            default:
             //show button here
        break;
           }
        }
     });
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. its Working as i Needed. But the strategy changed here. boss said me that you should load more images in the gridView on the scroll listner only not by using a Extra Button (Load More). Initially my gridView is filled with 12 images and 12 textViews. So How can i load more 12 images and text when i reached at the last Item of the GridView i.e the 12th item. Please Help in this regard.

Comment: @QadirHussain : see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170466/android-using-gridview-with-onscrolllistener) maybe helpful in solving current issue