# In Android how to have a gridView which executes a function each time it overscrolls?

Tags: android, gridview, overscroll

Android newbie here. I'm creating a Android app to display images in GridView(Using JsonParsing). When the app opened it will display first 20 images and when you scroll down to the last image or while Overscroll, It should download previous 20 images i.e I need to execute a function whenever this happens.. any help or suggestion is appreciated.. and I have the total number or count of images..

It is just like adding a "Load More" button at the end of the GridView but clicked automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!!! GridViews setOnScrollListener and in onScroll method you can define your condition just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170466/android-using-gridview-with-onscrolllistener)